# Long schema name of hadoop pig

Tags: schema, apache-pig

I have a complex job.

After several steps, now the schema come to below:

```
K: {C::group::sig: int,C::group::sn: chararray,long,DG::sn: chararray,DG::lat: float,DG::lng: float,DG::country: chararray,DG::region: int}
```

I can store and load, then re-assign the schema name for each item such as (sig:int, sn:chararray....)..

is there any other to do it in memory without load and store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At any time, you can rename a field when you `GENERATE` it.

```
DESCRIBE K;
K: {C::group::sig: int,C::group::sn: chararray,long,DG::sn: chararray,DG::lat: float,DG::lng: float,DG::country: chararray,DG::region: int}

K2 =
    FOREACH K
    GENERATE
        sig AS sig,
        C::group::sn AS sn,
        $2,
        DG::sn AS sn2,
        lat AS lat,
        lng AS lng,
        country AS country,
        region AS region;
DESCRIBE K2;
K2: {sig: int,sn: chararray,long,sn2: chararray,lat: float,lng: float,country: chararray,region: int}
```

Also note that if the name is unambiguous (e.g., `sig`), you do **not** need to use the full name when working with the field. If it is ambiguous (e.g., `C::group::sn` and `DG::sn`), you do need to use the full name.

Comment: Get it. Thank you. Also, I found flatten is another useful tools.